# Using for in construct to loop through Collections

Tags: javascript

First of all, I'm just a rookie here. I began my JavaScript lessons just a few weeks back via Wrox's "Beginning JavaScript" and so far, so good.

I became curious to why the author never used the `for in` looping statement to access the different objects in a collection. All the examples used the `for` statement to traverse along the Collections. So, I gave a shot at an example that traversed through all the link objects but used the `for in` construct. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function linkCounter_onload()
            {
                var linkObj = document.links;
                for(var linkIndex in linkObj)
                {
                    alert(linkObj[linkIndex].href);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="linkCounter_onload()">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://news.com">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://espn.com">ESPN</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, when I ran the code by opening the HTML page in Chrome, it first displayed three alert boxes each displaying the `href` of the respective links and then, it displayed three more alert boxes with the value `undefined`. I tested the page in IE, and Opera and all three including Chrome behave in the same manner but not Firefox in that it *doesn't display* the value `undefined` and there is also an extra alert popup.

If I change the function so that it uses a `for` loop instead, the code works perfectly. For example:

```
function linkCounter_onload()
{
   var linkObj = document.links;
   for(var linkIndex = 0; linkIndex < linkObj.length; linkIndex++)
   {
      alert(linkObj[linkIndex].href);
   }
 }
```

My instinct was to debug the code and see what's happening. I placed a watch on the `linkIndex` variable in Chrome to see what values it gets. On debugging, I observed that along with the `"0"`, `"1"` and `"2"` values, the `linkIndex` variable also gets some unexpected values like `"length"`, `"item"` and `"namedItem"` and then, the loop ends.

After that, I went to Firefox and used the default debugger to watch the linkedIndex variable and along with the above mentioned values, an extra value `"@@iterator"` was also seen.

Furthermore, I get the the same problem when I try to use `for in` with other collections.

---

I've learned that JavaScript can intelligently handle things like Arrays unlike C++ where I need to be careful to make sure that I don't cross the bounds (Not talking about Vectors). This was exciting to me as things were much simpler than C++.

So, why is this happening? Is it because of my misunderstanding of the working of `for in` construct? If not and if it indeed can traverse through any array, why are there problems when it comes to traversing a collection? Does it have any limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for...in` is best used to enumerate the *properties* of an object:

```
var foo = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
for(var varName in foo)
{
    console.log(varName + " : " + foo[varName]);
}
```

If you run it over an array-like structure:

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];
arr.foo = "bar";
for(var x in arr){
    console.log(x + " : " + typeof(x));
}
```

you'll notice that it enumerates *strings*, not numbers and pulls out stuff you wouldn't expect. It's really the wrong tool for the job and you should instead:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
    console.log(i + " : " + arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Reading your answer, I find that my current way of learning is too limited. I never knew how to create objects and define properties like the samples you mentioned. So far, I know how to create custom reference types.

Comment: My book mentioned using `for in` to traverse arrays. I thought arrays were a simple linear collection of data but I was wrong. Never knew after creating an array, you can expand it and add properties to it like you just did above.

`for in` will not just go through the array elements but also the properties and methods, right?

Answer (score 0):

the for .. in iterates only over enumerable properties
structured like this:

```
var o = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
```

if you try to `alert (linkIndex);` you will get

```
0
1
2
length
item
nameditem
```

if you `console.debug(linkObj);` before the loop starts, 
and open console at Developers  Tool (Chrome) you will get

```
[a, a, a, item: function, namedItem: function]
```

so?

the array linkObj is not 100% enumerable, and it has some other properties that does not necessarily be a key or index for this array.

thats why first 3 alerts are correct: 0 1 2, but the others are not

Ref:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in